# ActiveRecord - Display columns from multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a user, user_profile and profile_type models.  A user has_many user_profiles, a user_profile belongs_to a user and belongs_to a profile_type and a profile_type has_many user_profiles.

I have been reading on how to get this work but I am having problems figuring this out and any help would be much appreciated.

I know I could do this with SQL with a statement like this (freehand SQL, excuse mistakes), but I want to use ActiveRecord.

```
Select up.id, u.user_id, pt.connection_type
from user u
join user_profile up
on u.user_id = up.user_id
join profile_type pt
on pt.profile_type_id = up.profile_type_id
where u.username = "test"
```

I want to return nested user_profile objects for an associated user but I want the user_profile object to contain the profile_type.connection_type instead of the profile_type.profile_id.

Currently, if I do this,

```
user.user_profiles.all
```

add then iterate through the nested user_profiles that are returned, this is my output:

```
{
:id
:user_id
:profile_type_id
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
:id
:user_id
:profile_type.connection_type (instead of profile_type.profile_type_id)
}
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_profiles, autosave: true
  has_many :account_settings, autosave: true
end
```

User_Profile Model

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :profile_type
end
```

User Profile Type Model

```
class ProfileType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_profiles
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this using Grape.

Since the association was already created, I can use Grape entities to expose what I needed out of the associations.  It works seamlessly and I hope this helps anyone else who is having a similar problem.

To get what I was looking for, I needed to gather all user_profiles

```
userprofiles = user.user_profiles.all
```

Then, I presented this using Grape

```
present :user_profile_settings, userprofiles, with: API::V1::Entities::UserProfile
```

And, here is what my entities looked like:

```
  class UserProfile < Grape::Entity
    expose :profile_type, using: ProfileTypeEntity
  end

  class ProfileTypeEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :connection_type
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user.account_settings.select("profile_type.*, profile_type.connection_type").all
```

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain what you're doing and why it will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I tried that and this is the error I received:                                 [50] pry(main)> user.user_profiles.select("profile_type.*, profile_type.connection_type").all
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT profile_type.*, profile_type.connection_type FROM "user_profiles"  WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = $1
=> #<#<Class:#<UserProfile::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00000102eb0318>>:0x8175818c>